# Why adding extra state helps to update other state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6, react-native-paper

Here is the full code:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { View, ScrollView, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import {
  Appbar,
  Searchbar,
  List,
  BottomNavigation,
  Text,
  Button,
} from 'react-native-paper';

const AccordionCollection = ({ data }) => {
  var bookLists = data.map(function (item) {
    var items = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < item.total; i++) {
      items.push(
        <Button mode="contained" style={{ margin: 10 }}>
          {i}
        </Button>
      );
    }
    return (
      <List.Accordion
        title={item.title}
        left={(props) => <List.Icon {...props} icon="alpha-g-circle" />}>
        <View
          style={{
            flexDirection: 'row',
            flexWrap: 'wrap',
            alignItems: 'flex-start',
            backgroundColor: 'white',
          }}>
          {items}
        </View>
      </List.Accordion>
    );
  });
  return bookLists;
};

const MusicRoute = () => {
  const DATA = [
    {
      key: 1,
      title: 'Zain dishes',
      total: 21,
    },
    {
      key: 2,
      title: 'Sides',
      total: 32,
    },
    {
      key: 3,
      title: 'Drinks',
      total: 53,
    },
    {
      key: 4,
      title: 'Aesserts',
      total: 14,
    },
  ];
  const [data, setData] = React.useState(DATA);
  const [searchQuery, setSearchQuery] = React.useState('');
  const [sortAZ, setSortAZ] = React.useState(false);

  const onChangeSearch = (query) => {
    setSearchQuery(query);
    const newData = DATA.filter((item) => {
      return item.title.toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase());
    });
    setData(newData);
  };

  const goSortAZ = () => {
    setSortAZ(true);
    setData(
      data.sort((a, b) => (a.title > b.title ? 1 : b.title > a.title ? -1 : 0))
    );
  };

  const goUnSort = () => {
    setSortAZ(false);
    setData(DATA);
  };
  return (
    <View>
      <Appbar.Header style={styles.appBar}>
        <Appbar.BackAction onPress={() => null} />

        <Searchbar
          placeholder="Search"
          onChangeText={onChangeSearch}
          value={searchQuery}
          style={styles.searchBar}
        />

        <Appbar.Action
          icon="sort-alphabetical-ascending"
          onPress={() => goSortAZ()}
        />
        <Appbar.Action icon="library-shelves" onPress={() => goUnSort()} />
      </Appbar.Header>
      <ScrollView>
        <List.Section title="Accordions">
          <AccordionCollection data={data} />
        </List.Section>
      </ScrollView>
    </View>
  );
};

const AlbumsRoute = () => <Text>Albums</Text>;

const MyComponent = () => {
  const [index, setIndex] = React.useState(0);
  const [routes] = React.useState([
    { key: 'music', title: 'Music', icon: 'queue-music' },
    { key: 'albums', title: 'Albums', icon: 'album' },
  ]);

  const renderScene = BottomNavigation.SceneMap({
    music: MusicRoute,
    albums: AlbumsRoute,
  });

  return (
    <BottomNavigation
      navigationState={{ index, routes }}
      onIndexChange={setIndex}
      renderScene={renderScene}
    />
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  appBar: {
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
  },
  searchBar: {
    width: '60%',
    shadowOpacity: 0,
    borderRadius: 10,
    backgroundColor: '#e4e3e3',
  },
});

export default MyComponent;
```

[Expo Snack Link](https://snack.expo.io/@csdal/4fac88)

There are two weird mechanisms.

**First**

If I remove `sortAZ(true)` in `goSortAZ()` and `sortAZ(false)` in `goUnSort()`, the state `data` stops updating after you press on (1) sort and (2) unsort buttons more than three times.

**Second**

If I remove `DATA` array outside the component, sort and unsort buttons does not work/update.

If I do not remove these two, I can sort and unsort the list.
I feel that the code is messy although it achieves the function.

My questions is:

- Why adding extra state (sortAZ) helps to update other state (data)?

Comment: If you add a key in each button with the key of each item in the data, will it update correctly?

Comment: @NaySie you are not cloning the original array when sorting it. Please see my answer. I have just tested it and it works fine without setting the boolean variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just totally remove `sortAZ` variable (no need to use it unless you somehow want to have a `loading` status, but since you are not making http requests, that's not necessary) and replace `goSortAZ` with the following:

Remember to clone the original array in order to create a new copy and then sort that copy.
This is working fine.

```
  const goSortAZ = () => {
    setData(
      [...data].sort((a, b) => (a.title > b.title ? 1 : b.title > a.title ? -1 : 0))
    );
  };
```

i would suggest using the same technique for the unSort method too.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and answer.